# How to perform fast formatted input from a stream in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, stl, file-io

The situation is: there is a file with 14 294 508 unsigned integers and 13 994 397 floating-point numbers (need to read `double`s). Total file size is ~250 MB.

Using `std::istream` takes ~30sec. Reading the data from file to memory (just copying bytes, without formatted input) is much faster. Is there any way to improve reading speed without changing file format?

Comment: I think you should post your loop code

Comment: If this is MSVC libs you might want to investigate how much penalty you're incurring from SECURE_SCL (on by default). Take care to understand the implications of turning it off, though.

Comment: Sorry, that should be: _SECURE_SCL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to use STL style i/o? You must check out [this](http://www.dietmar-kuehl.de/cxxrt/cxxrt-1.0.4.tar.gz) excellent piece of work from one of the experts. It's a specialized `iostream` by Dietmar Kuhl.

I hate to suggest this but take a look at the C formatted i/o routines. Also, are you reading in the whole file in one go?

Comment: Syntax and approach doesn't matter :) And yes, i'm reading the whole file.

Comment: Have you tried fscanf and friends? I'd say give these a shot, and measure.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look at Matthew Wilson's FastFormat library:

- http://www.fastformat.org/

I haven't used it, but he makes some pretty impressive claims and I've found a lot of his other work to be worth studying and using (and stealing on occasion).

Comment: Maybe the techniques can be applied to input

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the format. It's possible that you could memory map it, or could read in very large chunks and process in a batch algorithm.

Also, you haven't said whether you know for sure that the file and process that will read it will be on the same platform. If a big-endian process writes it and a little-endian process reads it, or vice versa, it won;t work.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing input by yourself (atoi & atof), usually boosts speed at least twice, compared to "universal" read methods.

Answer (score 0):

Something quick and dirty is to just dump the file into a standard C++ string, and then use a stringstream on it:

```
#include <sstream>
// Load file into string file_string
std::stringstream s( file_string );
int x; float y;
s >> x >> y;
```

This may not give you much of a performance improvement (you will get a larger speed-up by avoiding iostreams), but it's very easy to try, and it may be faster enough.